# Send a message to chatroom if an argument isn't passed with command

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Can anyone give me some help on this issue? I am trying to throw out a message should someone try to use a command without giving an argument.

```py
    @feathelp.error
    async def name_feathelp(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArguement):
            await ctx.send("I need the name of the feat you want help on. I can't read minds.")
```

If I execute !feathelp without an argument to my bot, it gives me:

```py
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: answer is a required argument that is missing.
```

With the above method, I get:

```py
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands' has no attribute 'MissingRequiredArguement'
```

Not understanding why it's not an arttribute, when that exception was raised without the above code.

```py
    @commands.command()
    @commands.dm_only()
    async def feathelp(self, ctx, *, answer):


        featDictionary = featDict()[0]
        featList = featDict()[1]
        private = ctx.author.send
        answer = str(answer.lower())
        reqStat = featDictionary[0][answer]['stat']
        featStatus = featDictionary[0][answer]['status']
        level = featDictionary[0][answer]['requirements'][0]
        reqStr = featDictionary[0][answer]['requirements'][1]
        reqDex = featDictionary[0][answer]['requirements'][2]
        reqCon = featDictionary[0][answer]['requirements'][3]
        reqFeats = featDictionary[0][answer]['requirements'][4]
        await private(" ''' " + answer.capitalize() + " (" + reqStat + ") (" + featStatus + "):\n" +
                    featDictionary[0][answer]['desc'] +
                    "\nPrerequisites: " + "\nLevel: " + str(level) +
                    "\nStrength: " + str(reqStr) +
                    "\nDexterity: " + str(reqDex) +
                    "\nConstitution: " + str(reqCon) +
                    "\nRequired Feats: " + reqFeats +" ''' ")
```

Comment: "Argument" only has one "e": [`MissingRequiredArgument`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.MissingRequiredArgument)

Comment: I'm actually blind....wow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the argument to be **optional** you should change your fonction to :

```py
async def feathelp(self, ctx, *, argument = None):
```

This is will change `argument` as an **optional** one.

For the error handler `MissingRequiredArgument` is in `commands.error.MissingRequiredArgument` not just `commands`.

Hope it helped !